# Ellipsis for too long title of UIButton not shown

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I have problem with UIButton title. For too long text I have set truncate tail option, but instead `…` text is just cut.

How enforce ellipsis to show on button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
```

Comment: @Preetygeek Have you given proper width to Button? or Is it constrained with autolayout ?

Comment: Auto layout is setting it width.

Comment: Ok, setting it directly on label makes difference. I was thinking that setting it on button in xib will propagate value.

Comment: button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;